# Linux : How can I print line number and column number when values do not match for tab separated files using AWK in linux

Tags: linux, awk

Compare File 1 vs File2 and print line no. for difference record and column no of difference present in file2.

**In file1:**

```
User_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                       Postal_code 
User_1    fistname      Lastname    35, Park Lake, California           32068    
user2     Johnny        Depp        32, Park Lake, California               
user3     Tom           Cruise      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         32907    
user4     Leonardo      DiCaprio    Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           1230    
user5     Sylvester     Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33710   
user6     Srleo         Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33700
```

and

In file2:

```
User_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                       Postal_code     
User_1    fistname      Lastname    35, Park Lake, California           32068    
user2     Johnny        Depp        32, NEW Street, California          96206    
user30    Tom           Cruise      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         32907   
user4     Leonardo      DiCaprio'   Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           00000    
user5     Sylvester     Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33710   
user7     Nicolas       Cage                                            55010    
user6     Srleo         Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33700
```

**Expected Result:-

Difference in file2 is 
line number followed by column number (where the values do not match)**

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO- 4,5    
Line No. 3 COLUMN NO-1    
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 3,5    
Line No. 5 COLUNN NO 5    
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

**Note:** File size to be compare is in GB and File is tab separated and has more than 400 tab separated column.

I am using-

```
awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[$0]++;next}!($0 in Arr){print FNR}' file1 file2
```

However, it gives me the line numbers and not the Column Numbers

Comment: Once you find the appropriate line, you would then need to split and compare each column

Comment: How can we do that in UNIX? Can you please share the script. @grail

Comment: Check the split function from the manual :- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions ... Then simply use a for loop where you currently have 'print FNR'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do, however doesn't match your expected result

```
paste f1 f2 | 
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {n=NF/2} 
                  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                     if($i!=$(i+n)) 
                       {c=c s i; s=","} 
                   if(c) 
                     {print "Line No. " NR-1 " COLUMN NO " c;
                      c="";s=""}}'

Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 4,5
Line No. 3 COLUMN NO 1
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 3,5
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

either you're not comparing line by line or some following some other unwritten spec.

Comment: @ Thank you for the scirpt. Above logic is working for me.

Comment: Hi @ karakfa,

The above logic ignores te null values, how can we print the column number where the value has changed to  null or vice-versa

File 1
ID60   Mark Waugh St. Petersburg 7777700000

File 2
ID60    Mark Waugh St. Petersburg 7777700000
ID70    STEVE                    8888800000  (i.e. there are null values in col. 3 and 4)

Output:

line No. 2 : 1,2,3

Expected Output:

line No. 2 : 1,2,3,4,5  

can you please help me for the above expected result.

Comment: it will compare null fields as well.  The number of fields is set on the first line.  If you have a header not null for all columns they will be compared regardless of their value.  However, the field delimiters (here tab) should be in place even if the fields are missing.  Also, don't post formatted text in the comments, append your question with the new test case.